# sip username format for signing into office Communicator

Tags: c#, .net, lync, lync-2013

Is it possible to find out the username format for signing into lync because , the username will be the sip username format.

Because, if the emailaddress is `a@gmail.com`, then the username will be `someformat-a`. How to find out this username format?
Is it possible to obtain it manually or even C# programatically?

Answer (score 1):

I would be wary of trying to infer SIP addresses from email addresses particularly if you need the system to always get it right.  It's fairly common for sip addresses to differ completely from the email address in certain scenarios such as when women change their names after getting married.

The best approach would be to read the actual SIP addresses from Active Directory and import them into your system.

Comment: what would be the propertyname for the SIP address?Is it just rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value? Because this property is not allowing to login to the lync

Comment: It will be the property with the attribute msrtcsip-primaryuseraddress